# issue with css opacity and z-index

Tags: css, z-index, opacity

Inside a div .frame I have two divs: .main and .bottom.
They are both is the same position but .main has a higher z-index value.
When the mouse is over .frame the opacity of .main change to 0.5, so when the mouse is over .main we can see .bottom.
Without visibility: hidden how can I hide the content .bottom when the opacity of .main is 0.5?

my css are:

```
.frame{
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    width:100px;
}

.main{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index:2;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    width:100%;
}

.bottom{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index:1;
    width:100%;
}

.frame:hover .main{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

and my html:

```
<div class="frame">
    <div class="main">main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br></div>
    <div class="bottom">bottom<br>bottom<br>bottom<br></div>
</div>
```

here a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/MNTcz/

Comment: In your description, you said hovering over `.frame` changes `.main` to .85 opacity, but your code says .5

Comment: I cannot understand what are you trying to achieve. Why to hide `.bottom` when hovering `frame`. When do you want `bottom` to be visible?

Comment: @user3074592 with jQuery I'm using toggle() to show bottom

Comment: Please can you tell me what do you want ?Where is your float for the two divs ,what to do with the two divs .Where is width and height of the two divs !

Comment: Whenever you are going to hover the main it becomes opaque 0.5 and the second div bottom becomes visible for the opacity.Please follow some css rules for the html content.Otherwise how can you render it to your goal!

Comment: @user2461031 Please explain exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Change the opacity of the `.bottom` element to 0 while hovering on the `.frame` element.

Add this CSS:

```
.frame:hover .bottom {
    opacity:0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MNTcz/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Set the opacity of `.bottom` to `0` when hovering `.frame`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MNTcz/3/)

**CSS:**

```
.frame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}

.main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
}

.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

.frame:hover .main{
    opacity:0.5;
}

/*..... Add below style in ur css .........*/

.frame:hover .bottom {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: it is a solution, but when the mouse is over .main, with jQuery I'm using toggle() to show .bottom, so with your solution .bottom is empty.